# Get the coordinates of skeleton data using NITE skeleton tracker

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am able to track skeletons with a kinect. After running the command **roslaunch skeleton_markers markers.launch** it opens the Nite Skeleton tracker and I am able to track the skeletons. I want to ask if there is a way for me to get the coordinate data of the each joint that I have been able to track and if there is a way I would like to ask how to do it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252871/get-the-coordinates-of-skeleton-data-using-nite-skeleton-tracker/) by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daggarwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/30140/daggarwa/) on 2017-04-24**:
Hey can you tell how you got skeletal tracking working? did you use nite 2 with libfreenect2?on ros indigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The skeleton joints are published as a set of transform. You have to use a TransformListener object and then track the joint frame: head, neck, torso and so on...

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2017-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on 2017-01-25**:
@rastaxe Thank you for the answer. I tried following instruction from this link http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf  to understand how to use a transform but I am still not able to get it. I wanted to ask if you can explain  to me how to use a transform with skeleton_markers